# JavaScript setAttribute not working

Tags: javascript, setattribute

I've been trying to use setAttribute to change the name of the select tag from the oldName to the newName, however when I load the page and then look at the source, the oldName remains. Ultimately, I wanted to add an attribute "onchange","function();" but I can't even get the JS to change the name of the tag. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance. I tested this on Mac OS X: Chrome, FF, and Safari.

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
        <select name="oldName">
        <option value="0">Essay 1</option>
        <option value="1">Essay 2</option>
        <option value="2">Essay 3</option>
        </select>
<script type="text/javascript">
document.getElementsByTagName("select").item(0).setAttribute("name","newName");
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: the source won't change, all js changes are done on the DOM representation. to test the changes use firebug or the chrome developer tools

Comment: works fine for me in chrome 13.  [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/CJjYH/)

Answer (score 4):

Your code works, the name changes. You just won't see the name change when viewing source. Instead look at the generated source in a development tool. (Try `F12` in Chrome).

View Source only shows the source as it is first downloaded from the server. Using a development tool you can see the changes made to the DOM after page load.

Comment: Thank you! You're right. I don't know why I thought just viewing the source would display an updated version.

Answer (score 0):

When you do "view source", you are not looking at the HTML of the page as it exists in front of you - the browser fetches a copy of the page specifically to show you the source. When doing so, it does not interpret javascript - so any changes to the document you make via javascript will not be reflected in the "view source" window.

In order to view the changes to DOM *live*, you will have to use a development tool like Firebug ([link](http://getfirebug.com/)). Being a Firefox extension of course means no luck in Internet Explorer, which is why developers often target Firefox for development and worry about Internet Explorer after everything is reasonably up and running.

There ARE alternative tools for Firebug in IE (like Firebug Lite), but none come close to the functionality and utility.

Answer (score -3):

Why you dont use class instead? Like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    $('.example').attr('name','new');
});
</script>


<select class="example" name="oldName">
<option value="0">Essay 1</option>
<option value="1">Essay 2</option>
<option value="2">Essay 3</option>
</select>
```

Comment: That's jQuery, native DOM elements don't have `.attr`. Plus it does not make sense to set a function result to something.

Comment: This looks like a mix between pure JS and jQuery, and as there's no jQuery object, `attr` won't exist for the object you're trying to call it on. And as @pimvdb pointed out, you don't want to assign the string "newName" to the function.

Comment: Agreed - this is not valid. Please ensure that your answer contains factual information before posting - Thanks!